# Document Library office documents open with read view

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-server, document-library

I have come across interesting thing, that in one Document Library in SharePoint 2013, selecting Office Document default is `Open` and in other `Edit`

[image: Default is Open]
[image: Default is Edit]

How can I change that default behavior in Document Library? Can't find the option to change it, maybe I'm just missing something.

Difference is, that if first selection is `Open`, then document will open in `Read-Only` mode, but if first selection is `Edit`, then document will be opened directly in `Edit` mode.

When opening Infopath document, then it should not be opened in `Edit` mode.

**EDIT:**

I have noticed, that Word document in same Library opens first in `Read-Only` mode and you can choose to edit it.

But `Infopath forms` still open in `Design Mode`, not just in `Read-Only` (where you could fill fields. Maybe this help to understand a little better of my problem.

**EDIT 2:**

I came up with a idea, what if I make this list into Read-Only for people, who shouldn't have edit access to there anyway, but then I encountered another interesting problem..

This picture show, when I try to open InfoPath form from list item, when I have only read access (including opening Documetns)

Environment has Office 2016 installed and InfoPath 2013 (could this cause problems?)

[image: Appearing error, when only read only access]

**Found workaround!**

I discovered, that this problem is with IE 11 (version 11.0.9600.18427) and somehow the problem is only with InfoPath documents, if you try open them in Read-Only permissions. It worked with same permissions on Firefox, so I tried to use `Compatibility Mode` and it worked with `Edge` mode.

It's not the solution tho, but could help anyone with same problem!

Comment: are you talk about Default open behavior for browser-enabled documents:

Comment: Commented on your answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did it! Problem was that master page had following tag

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=10" />
```

So this forced this to work with IE 10 mode and following feature was bugged in that mode. So instead I changed that tag to following:

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
```

You can change your MasterPage content in SharePoint Designer and changes should affect instantly (you may need to check in).

**NOTE**

This is solution to my problem, this might help others. You can test it out, if anything works with different compatibility with F12 tool.

Answer (score 0):

If you talk about the Default open behavior for browser-enabled documents

- Go to list settings > Advanced setting > Default open behavior for browser-enabled documents:

[image]

Comment: This doesn't exactly change, if document is opened in `Edit` or `Read-Only` mode.